# Not able to bind value from other function

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, requirejs, knockout-mvc

I am working on Single page Application (durundaljs and knockjs for UI).
 on the view.js file

```
var vm= = function() {
            Id: ko.observable();
            Name: ko.observable();
            description: ko.observable();
            parentName:ko.observable();
}
```

on the page `activate()` method I am assigning values to observable properties.

```
var activate = function(Id) {

            getUserGroup(Id);
};
var getUserGroup = function(Id) {
            var ajaxOptions = {
                url: 'Api/Group/Get?id=' + Id,
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json'
            };

            function gotUserGroup(data) {

                vm.Id = data.Id;
                vm.Name = data.name;
                vm.description = data.description;
                vm.parentName =getName(data.parentId)                
            }

            return $.ajax(ajaxOptions).then(gotUserGroup);
        };

function getName(Id)
{
            var ajaxOptions = {
               url: 'Api/Client/Get?Id=' + Id,
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json'
            };
            function getValue(data) {
                return data.name;

            }

            $.ajax(ajaxOptions).then(getValue);
}
```

the issue I am facing is I am not able to get value assigned to the `parentName` property.
I have a query like how can we bind in knockoutjs.
Here in my situation,i need to get `parentId` value and based on it get the `parentname`.
and that value should bind to the `parentName` property.
Can anyone suggest how can i achieve this.

Comment: Your api call is not returning the value so you can't materialize it from thin air...  Have you considered returning the value of that object?

Comment: Thnaks I solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
var getUserGroup = function(Id) {
            var ajaxOptions = {
                url: 'Api/Group/Get?id=' + Id,
                type: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json'
            };

            function gotUserGroup(data) {

                vm.Id = data.Id;
                vm.Name = data.name;
                vm.description = data.description;
                vm.parentName =getName(data.parentId)  
return data;              
            }

    function getName(data.Id)
    {
                var ajaxOptions = {
                   url: 'Api/Client/Get?Id=' + Id,
                    type: 'GET',
                    dataType: 'json'
                };
                function getValue(data) {
                    return data.name;

                }

               $.ajax(ajaxOptions).then(getValue);
    }

            return $.ajax(ajaxOptions).then(gotUserGroup).then(getName);
        };
```